# The number '3' gets skipped in ruby-cucumber autoamtion

Tags: ruby, selenium, cucumber, selenium-chromedriver, watir

I have no idea why this is happening. I updated chromedriver. Updated Waitr. Updated Selenium. Asked on the page-object gems.

Whener I enter a number in my text fields the number three gets skipped. For example if I have '43241' it will bcome '4241'

```
text_field(:thisfield ,:id=>'IDforit',:frame=>frame)
on(myPage).thisField = 1037734912
```

I am using it like that (Where I have a myPage defined). This will for example output 10774912.

I am using page object, watir, ruby-cucumber

Comment: Is this an early April Fools question? ;)

Comment: Another possible fix (see the other comments in this thread, too): https://github.com/angular/protractor/issues/698#issuecomment-187783747

Comment: if you have updated chromedriver, be sure there is not an older version somewhere on your path ahead of wherever you stored the latest version when you updated.  you can use `chromedriver.exe -v` to see what version is being found.  Also if using a package manager or homebrew be sure it's really installing the latest version you can download manually, sometimes things like homebrew lag behind and will want to install an older version.